# Refactoring without eclipse

Tags: java, refactoring

I am currently working on a source tree with hundreds of java modules that reference eachother. I can't want to import them all into Eclipse because it becomes very confusing and slow. Are there any stand alone linux tools that can help me refactor code? If not, how can I go about doing this effectively without Eclipse?

** Edit I would like a tool that someone has used. I realize there are a lot of tools out there that may or may not work. I was hoping SO could help me by narrowing the list.

**Edit I appreciate the help but I don't really want to justify not using Eclipse for this operation. I already use it to edit 20 or so of these modules at a time. I can't keep the amount of source I want to in the workspace effectively.

Comment: What kind of refactorings do you want to do? Also, I don't understand what your problem with Eclipse is, so maybe you could elaborate on that. Is your computer too slow for it?

Comment: Thanks, I editted my question to answer this comment.

Comment: I would have thought Eclipse, like IntelliJ and Netbeans can handle 10K classes easily if you have enough memory. How many classes/modules do you have?

Comment: There is a lot of generated source. I inherited a code base of far more than 10k classes. Can Netbeans handle more than Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search returned [RefactorIT](http://javaboutique.internet.com/demoIDEs/RefactorIT/). That's as good as place as any to start.

I am also curious how Eclipse would make it more confusing. I can't imagine that manually organizing code would be less confusing than having Eclipse's project explorer, for example.

Comment: Well, for one thing they are nested source trees so using clipse tools lists the same files under each module. I could fix this if I wanted to spend a month editing all of my project files and tweeking them. I don't have time for that. Besides, it would still be slow and the only problem I have is refactoring. I realize that there are tools out there to do this. I guess my question was misleading. I was looking for someone who had experience with one that they could recommend. ~ Thanks

Comment: Now that I can't help with. I've only ever worked on serious refactoring within Eclipse. Out of ignorance, I'd ask why seeing a file listed multiple times in Eclipse would be bad (assuming you mean the same file and not copies of it)? Eclipse should be smart enough to recognize that it's the same file and only try to refactor it once. I would also speculate that re-organizing your code would also be part of your refactoring, assuming this code base will be staying around a while longer.